# displaying parent terms in taxonomy view title?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Taxonomy View with all nodes having a specific taxonomy term.

At the top of the view I can read the term name.

If the term is a children of another term, I would like to display the parent as well on the top of the View

> parent > children

How can I make it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved enabling breadcrumbs. They perfectly works with taxonomy terms as well

Answer (score 0):

Add in header of views php code, that will print parent of current term.